# Пытался сделать удаление сообщения при нажатии на реакцию

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@Bot.command()
async def woof(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xebebeb)
    embed.set_image(url=nekos.img('woof'))
    msg = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    await msg.add_reaction('❌')
@Bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction):
    if reaction.emoji == "❌":
        await Bot.message.delete()
```

но код не работает

Answer (score 0):

Ваш подход почти верный, за исключением того, что для удаления сообщения, надо сначала получить само сообщение)
Во первых вам нужно проверять эмодзи по имени - **reaction.emoji.name**

Дальше у Bot нету такого атрибута как **message**.
Поэтому прежде чем продолжать, нам надо получить само сообщение. **[fetch_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch%20message#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)** нам в этом поможет

```
@Bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
    if reaction.emoji.name == "❌":
        msg = await Bot.get_channel(reaction.channel_id).fetch_message(reaction.message_id)
        await msg.delete()
```